# What is the meaning of 'at compile-time' in Perl scripting?

Tags: perl, runtime, compile-time

I have read this about Perl:

> Perl is an interpreted language and doesn't compile.

And I also see talk of `at compile-time` and `at run-time`.

Especially when I look for use of `use` and `require`, it shows a difference:

> `use` normally loads the module *at compile time* whereas `require` does *at run time*.

Does Perl really compile the script? What is the meaning of 'at compile-time' in Perl scripting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl does compile, prior to running. Usually that's done immediately before.  Running `perl -c` will do a fairly basic code validity check, and will highlight certain classes of errors (usually in my case, missing semi-colons).

From [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

> After locating your program, Perl compiles the entire program to an internal form. If there are any compilation errors, execution of the program is not attempted. (This is unlike the typical shell script, which might run part-way through before finding a syntax error.)

That includes loading and checking any imported modules for the same tests. In *most* cases that's exactly what you want - these tests/errors are *usually* show stoppers, and so detecting before even starting to execute is a good thing.

Especially when you `use strict;` and `use warnings;` your code is preprocessed for a wider range of errors.  It is done at compile time, and it'll abort if anything it spotted.

Again, this is *usually* desirable - tripping over glitches halfway through a program is *usually* more annoying to sort out, as you're potentially in an inconsistent state.

However as you note - things like modules can be pretty big, and it can be useful as a result to load them 'on the fly'. Perl can redefine a bunch of things as you go - if you really want you can make/change subroutines within your code.

Changes to subroutines and testing their validity can't ever be done at "compile time" because of what is known as the halting state problem. So you load at run time, but then have to build in some more exhaustive integrity checking.

Comment: Lots of `use strict;` and `use warnings;` errors are actually caught at run-time. (e.g. `$x="abc"; $x->{def}` and `print undef;`)

Answer (score 5):

Perl code is compiled before it is executed, just not to machine code. It's a bit like how Java is compiled to byte code, but the result is higher-level.

```
# B::Concise shows the opcode tree that results from compiling Perl code

$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'print("Hello, world!\n") for 1..3;'
1  <0> enter
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <$> const[IV 1] s
5  <$> const[IV 3] s
6  <#> gv[*_] s
7  <{> enteriter(next->b last->e redo->8) lKS/8
c  <0> iter s
d  <|> and(other->8) vK/1
8      <0> pushmark s
9      <$> const[PV "Hello, world!\n"] s
a      <@> print vK
b      <0> unstack v
           goto c
e  <2> leaveloop vK/2
f  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

When Perl is asked to execute a file (because it was passed to `perl`, `require`, `do EXPR` or `eval EXPR`), it first compiles the entire file, then executes the code it just compiled.

If any `use` or `BEGIN` is encountered during the compile phase, then the `use` statement or `BEGIN` block is executed as soon as it finishes compiling.

```
# -c causes the main program to be compiled but not executed.

$ perl -c -E'
   say "abc";
   BEGIN { say "def"; }
   say "ghi";
'
def
-e syntax OK

$ perl -E'
   say "abc";
   BEGIN { say "def"; }
   say "ghi";
'
def
abc
ghi
```

Certain errors can be detected at compile-time.

```
$ perl -c -E'say "abc" "def";'
String found where operator expected at -e line 1, near ""abc" "def""
        (Missing operator before  "def"?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near ""abc" "def""
-e had compilation errors.
```

Others can't.

```
$ perl -c -E'$x={}; $x->[0]'
-e syntax OK

$ perl -E'$x={}; $x->[0]'
Not an ARRAY reference at -e line 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [How a Perl 5 Program Works](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/08/how-a-perl-5-program-works.html).
It state that

> There are two distinct phases of execution of a Perl 5 program: compile time and runtime.

It also describe the difference between `compile time` and `runtime`.